# Remove lines matching a grep pattern

Tags: bash, grep

I have several files which I have to remove lines matching a grep pattern and the line before, except for one specific file. I can spot the lines with :

```
grep -B1 --exclude="my_specific_file.txt" "my_pattern" *_files.txt /dev/null
```

I'd like to know if it is possible to remove the pattern in all `*_files.txt` with grep? If there is another option, I'm interested.

Comment: Please read. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -i~ -ne 'BEGIN { $pattern = qr/my_pattern/ }
              if (/$pattern/) { $p = "" }
              else { print $p; $p = $_ }
              print $p if eof && $p !~ /$pattern/;
             ' -- *_files.txt
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line and processes every line by the code specified after `-e`
- `-i~` replaces each files with the output of the script, keeping the old file as a backup with the `~` suffix
- we use the variable `$p` to keep the previous line. If the current line (`$_`) matches the parent, we clear the previous one, otherwise, we print it and remember the current line.
- at the end of each file, we print the last line unless it should have been skipped. Without this, the pattern on the very first line would remove the last line of the previously processed file.

Comment: Cheers, that helps a lot. Is it possible to exclude one file in your code, on which I need to keep the pattern ?

Comment: @Paillou: The easiest thing would be to recreate it from the backup ;-)

Comment: What exactly is the pattern you use and the file name you want to exclude? Maybe you can use extended globs in bash.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of shell and `ed`:

```sh
for file in *_files.txt; do
  if [ "$file" != my_specific_file.txt ]; do
    printf "%s\n" "g/my_pattern/-1,.d" w | ed -s "$file"
  fi
done
```

Note that `ed` uses POSIX Basic Regular Expression syntax. The command `g/my_pattern/-1,.d` will mark every line matching `my_pattern` and delete them and the preceding lines.

Comment: Side note: If using `zsh` instead of `bash`, you can use `*_files.txt~my_specific_file.txt` and remove the `if` check (Assuming the `EXTENDED_GLOB` option is enabled).